# get average value depending on month?

Tags: mysql

My table:

```
rating   date
   4    12/02/2013
   3    12/02/2013
  2.5   12/01/2013
   3    12/01/2013
  4.5   21/11/2012
   5    10/11/2012
```

If I give input as 3 the last three months (02,01,12), average of rating result should come

I tried by using `GROUP BY` but I get this result:

```
 rating   month
  3.5      02
 2.75      01
```

For the 12th month no rating so no output.....

My desired result:

```
 rating   month
  3.5      02
 2.75      01
   0       12
```

Comment: irrespective of years they(months) belongs to? and `21/11/2013`?

Comment: you want average rating ? then avg(rating) where month like ' ';

Comment: but i need result for last 3 months.....

Comment: i did some changes in question.........

Comment: your months are wrong. its 10,11,12 and not 01 ,02 ,12

Comment: look that its wrong months here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e381c/35

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you want to return months that do not exist.  If you do not have a calendar table with dates, then you will want to use something like the following:

```
select d.mth Month,
  coalesce(avg(t.rating), 0) Rating
from 
(
  select 1 mth union all
  select 2 mth union all
  select 3 mth union all
  select 4 mth union all
  select 5 mth union all
  select 6 mth union all
  select 7 mth union all
  select 8 mth union all
  select 9 mth union all
  select 10 mth union all
  select 11 mth union all
  select 12 mth 
) d
left join yourtable t
  on d.mth = month(t.date)
where d.mth in (1, 2, 12)
group by d.mth
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1364f/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT coalesce(avg(rating), 0.0) avg_rating, req_month
  FROM    yourTable
       RIGHT JOIN
          (SELECT month(now()) AS req_month
           UNION
           SELECT month(now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS req_month
           UNION
           SELECT month(now() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AS req_month) tmpView
       ON month(yourTable.date) = tmpView.req_month
 WHERE    yourTable.date > (  (curdate() - INTERVAL day(curdate()) - 1 DAY) - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
  OR ratings.datetime IS NULL
GROUP BY month(yourTable.date);
```